# Parse string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have string in format:

> **8:live:avishekh.bh 8:prakash.tndk 8:niraj.bajra**

I want these in the format :

> **[live:avishekh.bh, prakash.tndk, niraj.bajra]**

How could I achieve that in SQLServer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of stuff and replace:<kbd>[DEMO HERE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/835390)</kbd>

```
declare @string varchar(100)='8:live:avishekh.bh 8:prakash.tndk 8:niraj.bajra'

     select 
        '['+
        stuff(
        replace(@string,'8:',','),1,1,'')+']'
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
SELECT 
QUOTENAME(STUFF(REPLACE('8:live:avishekh.bh 8:prakash.tndk 8:niraj.bajra','8:',','),1,1,''))
```

QUOTENAME function is used for inserting square bracket in sql server